# Use data attribute to trigger tabs instead of href in materializecss

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

Materializecss framework uses element id in `href` attribute of anchor tag to trigger things controlled by javascript like modal, tabs, dropdown etc. Having anything starting with `#`, it is considered as a link to same page. This causes problem for search engine crawlers. They perceive it as an internal link to same page which causes unnecessary duplicate internal links.

I have raised an issue on github for this https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/3100

Even if they think to resolve it in upcoming version, till then I am looking for a workaround to this problem. I have tried making change in `materialize.js` by replacing occurances of href to some other attribute like `data-tab` and `hreflang` but it simple fails to render it as tabs.

Is there any way by which I can still achieve tabs functionality without getting harmed by `#` in href

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. When I create a mobile nav I'd use `<a href="#" data-activates="mobile-nav">` to target `<ul class="side-nav right" id="mobile-nav">`. Is the `href="#"` the problem?